# I'm trying to acces an item from my database in WP7 and output it

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, observablecollection

I have made a database for my application and it uses an sdf database. When I query the database and put it in an ObservableCollection I get the information but how do I access the elements within? Any help?

```
var mathItemsInDB = from Math_Info math in mathDB.Math_Information
                            where math.mathID == 0 select math;


        Math_Info_Items = new ObservableCollection<Math_Info>(mathItemsInDB);



        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private void displayProblem()
    {   
        //here i would like to display the mathproblem fetched from the db and not an already created array
        this.MathProblem.Text = mathProblems[problemNumber];    //displays the mathproblem/equation
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but `mathProblems.ElementAt()`?